# Is it possible to add an icon besides arrow in bootstrap accordion?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I'm using a bootstrap 4 accordion and I was trying to add an icon besides the arrow up/down icon. I've tried to add a row and both icon place inside a row but still can't figure out how to make these two inline.

Here's what I have tried so far.

`<div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">`

```
<div class="card mb-3">
    <div class="card-header" id="heading-1">
         <h5 class="mb-0 card-header-title"> 
            <a class="btn btn-link text-left collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse-1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse-1"> 
              Item 3 
            </a> 
         </h5>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse-1" class="collapse" data-parent="#accordionExample" aria-labelledby="heading-1">
        <div class="card-body"> 
            Description 1 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

`</div>`

CSS:

```
    .card-header-title > a {`
        display: block;
        position: relative;
    }
    .card-header-title > a:hover {
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    .card-header-title > a:after {
        content: "\f078"; /* fa-chevron-down */
        font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
        font-weight: 900;
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
    }
    .card-header-title > a[aria-expanded="true"]:after {
        content: "\f077"; /* fa-chevron-up */
    }
```

Result:
[image]

And this is what I expected:
[image: expected]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```css
.card-header-title > a {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

.card-header-title > a:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.card-header-title i.fa-chevron-up {
  display: none;
}

.card-header-title > a[aria-expanded="true"] i.fa-chevron-down {
  display: none;
}

.card-header-title > a[aria-expanded="true"] i.fa-chevron-up {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.1/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
  <div class="card mb-3">
    <div class="card-header" id="heading-1">
      <h5 class="mb-0 card-header-title d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
        <a class="btn btn-link text-left collapsed d-inline-flex justify-content-between w-100" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse-1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse-1">
          Item 3
          <span class="float-right">
            <i class="fa-solid fa-chevron-down"></i>
            <i class="fa-solid fa-chevron-up"></i>
          </span>
        </a>
        <span><i class="fa-solid fa-trash float-right ml-2"></i></span>
      </h5>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse-1" class="collapse" data-parent="#accordionExample" aria-labelledby="heading-1">
      <div class="card-body">
        Description 1
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.12.9/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```